# Implement a Photoshop Photo Filter on CSS

Tags: css, photoshop, mix-blend-mode

I want to recreate the result of Photoshop `Photo Filters` on css but not really sure which `mix-blend-mode` to use and how.
I know this is a fairly trivial task, but I still need a little hint.
Ideally, I would like to combine these two filters into **one**. Here are the filter details and some test colors

```
R E S U L T    C O L O R S        
                                  
+----------+  +----------+        
|          |  |          |        
|  f0f4e7  |  |  eac91a  |        
|          |  |          |        
+----------+  +----------+        
                                  
             ^                    
                                  
Photo Filter 2 Yellow (f9e31c)    
15% no preserve luminosity        
                                  
             ^                    
                                  
Photo Filter 1 Underwater (00c2b1)
8% no preserve luminosity         
                                  
             ^                    
                                  
I N I T I A L  C O L O R S        
                                  
+----------+  +----------+        
|          |  |          |        
|  ffffff  |  |  ebca1c  |        
|          |  |          |        
+----------+  +----------+
```

Comment: Read About [Mix Blend Mode](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_mix-blend-mode.asp) In detail!

Comment: I already know all this, but you can only make a choice if you know how filters work in Photoshop.